# Simple return Google Scripts function results in HTML template

Tags: google-apps-script

I have built a couple of simple functions which return cell values in Google Scripts. I have also created at simple template HTML file, and have tried following Google's [HTML Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service?hl=en)!, but my HTML template output still doesn't work for me.

Firstly, my JS in my .GS file:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TemplateName').evaluate();
}

function getStarData2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("key in here").getRange("A2").getValue();
  //Logger.log(ss);
  return ss;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
...<span><? getStarData2(); ?></span>...
```

I have tried a variety of different things to get it working, however, I find it either runs but nothing displays or it runs or it returns a variety of different errors depending on what I try.

I would imagine that this is a very simple fix for all you experts out there so your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posting some of your errors could help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<?= getStarData2(); ?>` instead of `<? getStarData2() ?>`.

That equals sign basically says, "Run this function and then print out whatever gets returned here." Otherwise, you're just running that function and doing nothing with the result.